# Kinetic energy of a rigid body

Tags: dynamics, energy

A homogeneous disk with radius $R$ and mass $m$ rolls without sliding on a horizontal fixed plane. Peripheral point $A$ has velocity $v$. Determine the kinetic force of the disk.

[image]

In my textbook they use this formula $E_k=(1/2)mv^2 + (1/2)I_c w^2  $ and find $I_c=(1/2)mR^2$ but I don't understand why $w=v/R(\sqrt 2) $.

Answer (score 1):

v = sqrt(2) x w, because the disc is instantaneously rotating about the point of contact with the ground and A is at a distance of sqrt(2)XR (from Pythagoras theorem), hence w and v have that relation. Mind that v is the velocity of A (as in diagram) and not the centre of mass.

Answer (score 0):

You know the velocity $v$ of point $A$. The angular velocity $\omega$ can (in planar kinematics) be derived from the distance of the point to its center of rotation and its velocity (generally $\vec{v}_A = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}_A$ or $v_A=\omega \cdot r_A$ in 2D). The center of rotation of a non-sliding circle is always its contact point $P$ with the surface it is rolling on. Hence, from the pythagorean theorem, you can gain the angular velocity $w=v/R(\sqrt2)$. You can then use the textbook formula you gave to calculate the kinetic energy.